# d3.js: Scatter-plot zoom to displayed values only

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, scatter-plot

I am working on a scatter-plot in d3.
My data is organized as follows:

- Northern cities

  - best 10 performers
  - worst 10 performers
- Center cities

  - best 10 performers
  - worst 10 performers
- Southern cities

  - best 10 performers
  - worst 10 performers

For each category there is a tick box that allows the user to hide/show relevant observations. I do this by filtering data and then changing the "display" attribute to "none"/"display". (lines 285-365)

```
//BUTTONS
var filterNord = d3.select("#filterNord");
var filterNordTopTen = d3.select("#filterNordTopTen");
var filterNordBottomTen = d3.select("#filterNordBottomTen");
var filterCentro = d3.select("#filterCentro");
var filterCentroTopTen = d3.select("#filterCentroTopTen");
var filterCentroBottomTen = d3.select("#filterCentroBottomTen");
var filterSud = d3.select("#filterSud");
var filterSudTopTen = d3.select("#filterSudTopTen");
var filterSudBottomTen = d3.select("#filterSudBottomTen");

//--Generic functions
function filterParent (parent, childTop, childBottom, family) {
parent
  .on("click", function () {
    if (parent.classed("on")==true) {
    //hide data
    chart.selectAll("circle")
      .filter(function (d) {return d.gruppo == family;})
      .attr("display", "none")
    //change class
    parent.attr("class", "off")
    //change children
    childTop.property("checked", false);
    childTop.attr("class", "off");
    childBottom.property("checked", false);
    childBottom.attr("class", "off");
      } else {
    //show data
    chart.selectAll("circle")
      .filter(function (d) {return d.gruppo == family;})
     .attr("display", "display")
    //change class
    parent.attr("class", "on")
    //change children
    childTop.property("checked", true);
    childTop.attr("class", "on");
    childBottom.property("checked", true);
    childBottom.attr("class", "on");
      }
  ;})
  }

function filterChild (child, parent, sibiling, family, rank) {
child
  .on("click", function () {
    if (child.classed("on")==true) {
    //hide data
    chart.selectAll("circle")
      .filter(function (d) {return d.topTen == rank && d.gruppo == family;})
      .attr("display", "none")
    //change class
    child
      .attr("class", "off")
    //change parent if necessary
      if (sibiling.classed("on") == false) {
        parent.property("checked", false).attr("class", "off");}
      } else {
    //show data
    chart.selectAll("circle")
      .filter(function (d) {return d.topTen == rank && d.gruppo == family;})
      .attr("display", "display")
    //change class
    child
      .attr("class", "on")
    //change parent if necessary
      if (parent.classed("on")==false) {
        parent.property("checked", true).attr("class", "on")}
      }
  ;})
  }

filterParent (filterNord, filterNordTopTen, filterNordBottomTen, "N");
filterChild (filterNordTopTen, filterNord, filterNordBottomTen, "N", "1");
filterChild (filterNordBottomTen, filterNord, filterNordTopTen, "N", "0");
filterParent (filterCentro, filterCentroTopTen, filterCentroBottomTen, "C");
filterChild (filterCentroTopTen, filterCentro, filterCentroBottomTen, "C", "1");
filterChild (filterCentroBottomTen, filterCentro, filterCentroTopTen, "C", "0");
filterParent (filterSud, filterSudTopTen, filterSudBottomTen, "S");
filterChild (filterSudTopTen, filterSud, filterSudBottomTen, "S", "1");
filterChild (filterSudBottomTen, filterSud, filterSudTopTen, "S", "0");
```

When values get hidden I would like the chart to zoom only on the remaining points. I understand that  I should change the data set thorugh the .exit() selection and then .remove(). After I can change scales accordingly. I tried in two ways, but neither works.

```
//Update data to points that do not belong to the category I need to              hide (i.e. N)
dataset = dataset.filter(function (d) {return d.gruppo!="N";})
//Remove data in the exit selection
d3.selectAll("circle").data(dataset).remove();

//Update data only to the category I want to show again
dataset = dataset.filter(function (d) {return d.gruppo=="N";})
//Call the draw function
draw();
```

But this creates problems (e.g. wrong data is deleted; circles change color as I hover over them, which I find quite strange). I thought the problem was the filter function (due to the != operator); so I tried with a different filter, e.g:

```
//Update data to points that belong to the categories I wish to          keep (i.e. C and S)
dataset = dataset.filter(function (d) {return d.gruppo!=="C" && d.gruppo!=="S";})
//Remove data in the exit selection
d3.selectAll("circle").data(dataset).remove();

//Update data only to the category I want to show again
dataset = dataset.filter(function (d) {return d.gruppo=="N";})
//Call the draw function
draw();
```

This worked fine for the first hide/show iteration but then it does not work anymore.

I have read tons of articles on .exit() and .enter() but either I do not get some fundamental point of how they work, or I am implementing them wrong.

[bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/Federicopvs/raw/08423047c9fa3be8dfbc/) -- [gist](https://gist.github.com/Federicopvs/08423047c9fa3be8dfbc)

Comment: To make them available again you can just change the data again.

Comment: Not sure how to achieve this. Is this a good starting point?

    d3.selectAll("circle")
          .filter(function (d) {//filter function;})
          .exit()
          .remove()

and then the same with enter().append() instead of exit().remove()..

Comment: See [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles/).

Comment: Thanks I've been through that (and several more) but something is still unclear. I understand that exit() works on all data that i unbound to elements. My understanding is that I need to first remove values from dataset, then run exit().remove() right?
How do I remove the values though? I create variables according to each filter e.g.
var north = d3.selectAll("circle").filter(function (d) {return d.region=="nord";)
and then tried stuff like dataset.shift(north) or dataset.remove(north) but these are not correct..
What am I missing? :/

Comment: You need to modify the original data, i.e. what you're passing to D3's `.data()` function.

Comment: Exactly how do I remove data from a dataset based, for instance, on a filter?

Comment: `data = data.filter(...)`.

Comment: You need to specify a key function to `.data()`, e.g. `.data(dataset, function(d) { return d.id; })`.